# Can a content database upgrade be stopped and resumed?

Tags: 2013, upgrade, content-database

When you run the SharePoint management shell cmdlet [Upgrade-SPSite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161257.aspx) `-VersionUpgrade` to upgrade a 2010 database to 2013 it can take a really long time, sometimes days. Suppose you experience a power outage while it's in the middle of the upgrade process. Can this be resumed where it left off, or does it have to be started from scratch again? If so, how do you resume it?

Answer (score 2):

It is a SQL script run against the database, so like most transactions, the transaction would be rolled back and started from anew.

Comment: Thanks +1, do you know which SQL script it is? I always thought it was procedural code denoted by heavy CPU usage in powershell console process.